# URL со слешем в конце - на URL без слеша, с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Подскажите, как это реализовать?
Облазил весь гугл, ни одно решение не помогло. Так же видел здесь ответ:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Тоже безрезультатно.

Весь .htaccess:

```
#задаем кодировку сайта
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# Следовать за символическими ссылками или нет(симлинки)
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Запрет выдачи листинга пустого каталога
Options -Indexes

# По умолчанию файлы
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# перенаправляем дубль главной страницы модуля page/homepage
Redirect 301 /page/homepage /

# Включаем механизма преобразования
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css¦js¦jpg¦gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# Что бы перенаправить пользователей на сайт с WWW префиксом
# 
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\.ua$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "тут ссылка на сайт"$1 [R=301,L]
#
# Что бы перенаправить пользователей на сайт без WWW префикса
# 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "ссылка на сайт/"$1 [R=301,L]

#в случае index.php: 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "ссылка на сайт/" [R=301,L]
```

'

Comment: Ну, раз не помогло, покажите ВЕСЬ .htaccess свой (прямо в вопросе).

Comment: скинул полный htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте такой код добавить в .htaccess в корне сайта:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Visman, спасибо за ответ, в вашем случае убирает слеш в конце, но добавляет index.php - было: http://site.ru/pppp/catalog/product/, после преобразования 'http://site.ru/index.php/pppp/catalog/product' .

Comment: @ЕвгенийГуба, а я разве зря написал `RewriteEngine On` первой строкой? Сразу после этой команды вторую и третью строки ставить надо!

Comment: нет конечно не зря. поправьте тогда меня если я неправ - "RewriteEngine On" - включает механизм преобразования и как я понял его нужно использовать только 1 раз в документе. выше в своём вопросе, я скинул полную версию своего htaccess и там уже присутствует "RewriteEngine On"

Comment: @ЕвгенийГуба, в моем комментарии написано: `Сразу после этой команды вторую и третью строки ставить надо!` - 2 и 3 строка тут: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$` и `RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,L,QSA]` Поставьте эти строки после своего `RewriteEngine On` и перед всеми вашими правилами.

Comment: Благодарю вас за содействие - заработало. Последний вопрос, раз вы человек знающий - можете порекомендовать ресурс, где самому можно познакомиться по ближе с синтаксисом регулярных выражений?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГуба, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F и для тестов https://regex101.com/